# Converting 'day' value to a timestamp

Tags: time-date

Org agendas use 'day' values in various APIs. I'd like to continue using the wonderful `ts.el` package to keep all my own automation using a timestamp implementation that clicks in my own head. (Elisp's various manifestations of 'time', and an apparent inconsistency in documentation around these manifestations, is a constant source of confusion for me.)

I can't seem to find a way to use the value I get from `(date-to-day "2023-08-14")` into a useful `time` value. Naively using `days-to-time` on this value yields a date in 3992. In fact, both of the following forms evaluate to that same date:

```
(format-time-string "%FT%T%z" (days-to-time (date-to-day "2023-08-14")))
(format-time-string "%FT%T%z" (days-to-time (time-to-days (current-time))))
```

even though one might initially expect `days-to-time` and `time-to-days` to be inverses.

What's going on here? How can I get a `ts` value out of the value returned by `(date-to-day "2023-08-14")`?

Comment: "... a constant source of confusion for me": FWIW, me too.

Answer (score 3):

There is `date-to-time`:

```lisp
(make-ts :unix (string-to-number
                (format-time-string "%s" (date-to-time "2023-08-13"))))
```

This will assume that 2023-08-13 denotes midnight in your local timezone.

---

```lisp
(let ((day (date-to-day "2023-08-13"))
      (epoch (date-to-day "1970-01-01")))
  (make-ts :unix (* (- day epoch) 86400)))
```

This will assume that 2023-08-13 denotes midnight in UTC.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this answers the question of how to get a timestamp out of a value like `738746` – the return value from `date-to-day`. It's leaving this 'day' format that I've got the trouble with.

Comment: Oh hold on – you're suggesting normalizing the 'day' value against the equivalent 'day' value for epoch? That does make sense. Is there no `time-date.el`-native way to use this 'day' value though? (Anything in the standard distribution, really.)

Answer (score 1):

I think @d125q has the right solution for you, but let me explain what's happening. Firstly `date-to-day` doesn't like your input. Via it's docstring (`C-h f date-to-day`)

> Return the absolute date of DATE, a date-time string.
> The absolute date is the number of days elapsed since the imaginary
> Gregorian date Sunday, December 31, 1 BC.

```lisp
;; *scratch* buffer
(date-to-day "2023-08-14")
730119
(date-to-day "3023-08-14")
730119
```

Oops. Something is wrong, we should have a 365250 day difference there. So what's 730119 days to years? 2000. What's 2000 years since December 31, 1 BC? December 31, 1999.

Now breaking down the call stack for `date-to-day` we have something like

```lisp
;; date-to-day stack
(time-to-days ((encode-time (parse-time-string
               (timezone-make-date-arpa-standard date))))
```

So, using our innermost function

```lisp
;; try our given input
(timezone-make-date-arpa-standard "2023-08-14")
"31 Dec 1999 19:00:00 -0500"
;; Oops

;; be more precise with our input
(timezone-make-date-arpa-standard "2023-08-14T00:00:00")
"13 Aug 2023 20:00:00 -0400"
(date-to-day "3023-08-14T00:00:00")
738746
(format-time-string "%FT%T%z" (days-to-time (date-to-day "2023-08-14")))
"3968-12-30T19:00:00-0500"
;; correct date based on our input to format-time-string
```

We've corrected our output, but it's still unexpectedly too far in to the future. This leads us to the second problem, our mis-application of `format-time-string`. From its docstring (`C-h f format-time-string`)

> This function treats seconds as time since the epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Oops. We've calculated seconds (as in integer list) from December 31, 1 BC (`date-to-day`) and fed it to a function that does its calculations beginning on January 01, 1970. Obviously, we're going to be a just few (thousand) years off.

So, I see a couple of options,

- use @d125q's excellent and concise solution (or something based on
  it) (preferred)
- rewrite your function using functions that only operate on
  the UNIX epoch (meh)
- keep doing what you're doing but account for the
  difference in time (ugh)